# getting mutlitple row for a Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table as

```
userid cycleid ratings
1        13      5
1        14      6
1        15      7
```

I have to display data as

```
userid    2011 2012 2013
1          5    6    7
```

as you can see cycleid 13 is for year 2011, cycleid 14 for year 2012 and cycleid 15 for year 2013

MY QUERY

```
SELECT PER.USERID,
(SELECT max(PER1.RATING) FROM PERFRATINGS PER1 WHERE PER1.CYCLEID = 13) as 2011,
(SELECT max(PER2.RATING) FROM PERFRATINGS PER2 WHERE PER2.CYCLEID = 14) as 2012,
(SELECT max(PER3.RATING) FROM PERFRATINGS PER3 WHERE PER3.CYCLEID = 15) as 2013

FROM PERFRATINGS PER

Where PER.USERID = 1
```

gives multiple row (3 times)

```
userid    2011 2012 2013
1          5    6    7
1          5    6    7
1          5    6    7
```

I want everything in single row.

Comment: thanks..works..how did i miss that..:)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `pivot`

```
select * from
  (select userid, cycleid, ratings from perfratings)
  pivot 
  (max(ratings) for (cycleid) in (
     12 as 2012,
     13 as 2013,
     14 as 2014
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fix your query using `group by` or `distinct`.  A more efficient version would use `pivot` (if available in your version of Oracle) or conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT PER.USERID,
       max(case when PER1.CYCLEID = 13 then PER1.RATING end) as 2011,
       max(case when PER1.CYCLEID = 14 then PER1.RATING end) as 2012,
       max(case when PER1.CYCLEID = 15 then PER1.RATING end) as 2013
FROM PERFRATINGS PER
Where PER.USERID = 1
GROUP BY PER.USERID;
```

In a sense, the `group by` is redundant when you are looking only at one user.  However, you can remove the `where` and see the results for all users.